# stretch and contract a curve using matlab

Tags: matlab, curve

Let's suppose that there is a vector X with size N.

I want to stretch the curve (the one resulting after executing the command plot(1:N,X) ) to obtain a new curve with a different number of elements but with the "same" form.

In other words, the effect that I am looking is as someone stretches the curve from one side to outside (increasing the number of elements), or push the curve to inside (reducing the number of elements).

Any idea?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you try to achieve. Aren't you just looking for `interp1`? Please post example data and a picture.

Comment: So like this: `plot((1:N)*2,X)`?

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.guitarpitchshifter.com/)?